# Get webpart properties within display template

Tags: web-part, display-template, content-search-web-part

Is there anyway to get the webpart properties from within a display template html file, such as the Title in the Appearance tab as shown below or any properties under the Advanced section.

I would like to the get the Title and a URL and render the title inside the control template.

[image]

Edit: Solved it. I set the Chrome type back to default then I used the jQuery from the Singh to get the Title that had the TitleURL attached to it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Export the properties so you could use them in code or just render their values on the page?

Comment: I would like to get the title and render it within a div in the control template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some jQuery inside your custom control display template to fetch the title element (like below)

```
var MainWebPartSelector = "#" + ctx.ClientControl.get_id();

var titleElement = $($(MainWebPartSelector).parent().siblings().find("h2.ms-webpart-titleText span")[0]);
```

But I admit, I too would be interested if there is anything "*already available*" within the control template.

Comment: Is there any way to get properties under the Advanced section? Thanks

Comment: Solved using this jQuery. See edit in post.

Comment: Glad to have helped!